# Is my interpretation as to why we use trigonometric functions so much in mechanics correct?

Tags: classical-mechanics, vectors

I tried to have my question answered reading a question related to this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957657/why-are-the-trigonometric-functions-so-important) but it didn't really do it for me. Our questions, however are very similar but I think mine asks a slightly different question, being that it is less general and I'm asking through its ubiquity in physics.

Trigonometric functions are *everywhere* in physics (especially mechanics) and it's gotten me scratching my head as to whether I could explain well *why* that is.

I'm going to whimsically attempt to explain why it appears in mechanics and, more broadly, when dealing with vectors. I do this because I feel like it's a concise way for me to explain what I think I know about something and lays any of my logical fallacies noticeably naked to be corrected. Please let me know if I'm wrong and about what:

- Any line can be composed of two smaller line segments orthogonal to each other. This is basically axiomatic.
- We arbitrarily put an arrow on our line to imply direction. It is in now a vector space. We choose to do vectors in such a vector space because nature appears to agree with the results of experiments that subsequently prove that using the rules of such a space produces accurate results.
- Any vector can now be composed of two smaller vectors orthogonal to each other.
- When thinking about mechanics, it is useful to isolate motion in the $x$ and $y$ dimensions, because they do not interfere with each other (this is relatively axiomatic..?)
- With angle $\theta$ next to the origin, the $x$ component vector can be proven to be the cosine of $\theta$ and the $y$ component the sine of $\theta$.
- Thus, when modeling the motion of objects that does not move in one direction solely, $x$ and $y$ vector components are a useful way to solve problems in mechanics because all vectors effecting an object can be broken into vectors either orthogonal or in the same dimension to each other. This means they can be considered individually, as things vectors with magnitudes in the same direction undergo arithmetic just like normal numbers do, as vectors of Rank 0 are act in the same way normal real number arithmetic is conducted.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing you said was wrong, but there were some things missing, and some extraneous things. Here are the most important parts of what you said, plus a little more information that makes the explanation more fundamental.

There are actually two reasons for the prevalence of trigonometric functions in physics. The first is

**because we do a lot of trigonometry.**

Specifically, if we choose some set of coordinates, whenever a vector* is not parallel to any coordinate vector, a right triangle can be drawn with the vector as the hypotenuse, with one leg parallel to one coordinate vector.

Assuming the vector has length $L$, and the right triangle that we just drew has an opening angle of $\theta$, we can say that the leg opposite the angle $\theta$ has length $L\sin{\theta}$, and the leg adjacent to the angle $\theta$ has length $L\cos{\theta}$. These two legs have physical meaning - the opposite leg is the *component* of the vector parallel to the chosen coordinate vector, and the adjacent leg is the *projection* of the vector onto the plane defined by the other two vectors. This decomposition of vectors can be continued until the result is parallel to one of the coordinate vectors, at which point we have a complete decomposition of the vector into components parallel to each of the coordinate vectors. Each time, the trigonometric functions are necessary to determine the lengths of each component.

This decomposition is enormously useful in classical mechanics mainly because many common systems are vulnerable to a clever choice of coordinates. If you choose your coordinates correctly, then, for example, the dynamics of the system might always be parallel to one of the coordinate vectors, greatly simplifying the analysis of the system.

The second reason is

**because harmonic oscillators are everywhere.**

The trigonometric functions are solutions to one of the simplest nontrivial second-order differential equations:

$$\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} = -\omega x$$

This differential equation models an abstract physical system called a *simple harmonic oscillator.* Many complicated systems reduce to a simple harmonic oscillator when they are perturbed from their natural equilibrium by a small amount. Thus, the trigonometric functions describe the dynamics of a wide swath of problems, from a mass on a spring to electromagnetic radiation.

*The fact that the space we live in can be represented as a vector space is a fundamental assumption of classical mechanics.